# Go share cookie with development frontend

Tags: go, authentication, cookies

I'm using cookies for authentication in my Go server. The login basically does:

```golang
                cookie := &http.Cookie{
                    Name:     "secret",
                    Value:    "secretValue",
                    Domain:   "localhost",
                    Path:     "/",
                    Expires:  time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour),
                    Secure:   true,
                    HttpOnly: false,
                }
                c.Writer.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", cookie.String())
```

In my browser if I navigate to the backend (port 8000) and login with the html I created, it works, but if I go to my react frontend(port 3000), I see the cookie in the response of my fetch request to login, but any subsequent requests to the API do not have the cookie.

Here are my CORS settings:

```golang
    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"}, // This will remain * until a good func for dev and release is made to replace it.`AllowOriginFunc: `
        AllowMethods:     []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge:           24 * time.Hour,
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `AllowOrigins`. Maybe this was because * didn't include all ports.

```golang
    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8000"}, // This will remain until a good func for dev and release is made to replace it.`AllowOriginFunc: `
...
```